# Cannot attach to .mdf file after changing physical directory of solution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-express, entity-framework-migrations

I am following an MVC4 tutorial on Pluralsight, and all of my demo projects are source controlled through Visual Studio Online currently I am only testing locally (not deployed to Azure or anything). I am developing an ASP.NET MVC4 applications leveraging EF5, code first model. I enabled migrations, and the following class was created which I updated the seed method for and turned on automatic migrations.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext context)
    {
        context.MyCollection.AddOrUpdate(v => v.attr1,
            new MyProject() { attr1 = "MVC4", attr2 = 120},
            new MyProject() { attr1 = "LINQ", attr2 = 200});

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I am using the default connection string to my localDb instance with the dynamic data directory (not hard-coding the path).

```
"AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext.mdf"
```

Everything was working as expected until I decided to change the physical directory of my solution. I changed the directory from the default `C:/user/documents/visual studio 2013/projects` folder over to another storage drive at `D:/VisualStudio`. I updated the mapping for my source control and pulled down the project to the new location.

However, when I run my project, I no longer have any data. In fact, I cannot run the `update-database` command without receiving the following error message:

> Cannot attach the file 'D:\Visual Studio\MyProject\MyProject\App_Data\MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext.mdf' as database 'MyProject.Models.MyProjectContext'.

I attempted to turn off automatic migrations, re-run the "enable-migrations" command, and attempted hard-coding the path to store the `.mdf` file, but it can never "attach" to the database. I know that the database is no longer there, but I though if I ran the `update-database -force` command, if the system didn't find the database, it would create a new one.

Can someone assist on what I can do to regain my `.mdf` file in the `App_Data` folder?

Retaining existing data is a non-issue, I just need to have a new database to continue to work out of for the tutorial.

Comment: There have been times where this is caused when the PC user has no access to the Sql Server on your dev machine. Are you using localDb or a named Sql Instance?

Comment: @Komengem I am using localDb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of options you can try out and you app should be able to run again.

**Option 1**

Rename your database name in the web.config file, then run `Update-Database` again.

**Option 2**

remove the following line from web.config file, then run `Update-Database` again.

`AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|DataContext.mdf`

**Option 3**

Since you have enabled migration, delete the database from Server Explorer, and from Object explorer and the .mdf file from `app_data` folder in your app. Then run `Update-Database` again.

**I believe all those options should be able to work**

Comment: I changed the DB name in the connection string and it worked, thank you. As soon as I ran the Update-Database command, the old instance of the db disappeared from SSMS and the new one appeared. I am curious as to why this worked though? Is the old name of the database instance cached somewhere and only changing the config file triggered a change?

Comment: @JordanBrooker yes, when you delete the database in server explorer (usually not enough), you have to delete it from object explorer too and get rid of the old mdf file.

Comment: what I am curious about is when I changed my mapping for source control from the C: to the D:, I deleted all of my project folders from the C:, including the App_Data folder which contained my .mdf file. If the old file was no longer stored on disk, did IISExpress cache it or does the migrations plumbing keep an internal reference to the .mdf file that is not exposed through solution explorer in VS?